# Zabbix docker environment - specify MySQL certificate

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, zabbix

I'm trying to configure docker-compose yaml for zabbix and getting this message:

```sh
Creating network "zabbix_default" with the default driver
Creating zabbix_server ... done
Attaching to zabbix_server
server_1   |  Preparing Zabbix server
server_1   |  Using MYSQL_USER variable from ENV
server_1   |  Using MYSQL_PASSWORD variable from ENV
server_1   |  Using MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD variable from ENV
server_1   | ********************
server_1   | * DB_SERVER_HOST: here-is-my-db-host.mdb.yandexcloud.net
server_1   | * DB_SERVER_PORT: 3306
server_1   | * DB_SERVER_DBNAME: zabbix
server_1   | ********************
server_1   | **** MySQL server is not available. Waiting 5 seconds...
server_1   | **** MySQL server is not available. Waiting 5 seconds...
```

But MySQL server is ready. I suppose it's because of mysql ssl сertificate file. We are using `yandex cloud` db and it requires one. In python we have connection string of that format:

```
mysql+pymysql://user:password@here-is-my-db-host.mdb.yandexcloud.net/db_name?ssl_ca=/path/to/ssl_cert.crt
```

I think with docker I should specify `ssl_ca` some similar way, but I don't know how.

Here is my `zabbix_server` service configuration:

```yaml
server:
    container_name: zabbix_server
    image: zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:alpine-5.0-latest
    external_links:
      - "zabbix_gateway:zabbix-java-gateway"
    volumes:
      - "./.conf:/etc/zabbix/"
    ports:
      - "10051:10051"
    environment:
      MYSQL_SERVER_HOST: "here-is-my-db-host.mdb.yandexcloud.net"
      MYSQL_USER: "api"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "zabbix"
      MYSQL_SSL_CA: "/etc/zabbix/root.crt"
      ZBX_JAVAGATEWAY: "zabbix_gateway"
    restart: always
```

As you can see above I have set `MYSQL_SSL_CA` variable trying to make zabbix apply certificate. Besides this I have tried these variables:

```
MYSQL_SSL_CERT
MYSQL_SSL_KEY
DB_SSL_CERT_PATH
MYSQL_SSL_CERT_PATH
ZBX_DBTLSCAFILE
```

and some others (now I just can't remember which ones). Still, the same result.

What should I do to make zabbix container read this certificate (or simply connect the database)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `MYSQL_SSL_CA` variable in the Zabbix docker image, but there are, currently undocumented (at least for the README.md):

```
  configuration   |      variable
---------------------------------------
 DBTLSConnect       ZBX_DBTLSCONNECT
 DBTLSCAFile        ZBX_DBTLSCAFILE
 DBTLSCertFile      ZBX_DBTLSCERTFILE
 DBTLSKeyFile       ZBX_DBTLSKEYFILE
 DBTLSCipher        ZBX_DBTLSCIPHER
 DBTLSCipher13      ZBX_DBTLSCIPHER13
```